# Missing required parameters for [Route: havence.automail.edit] [URI: havence/automail/{automail}/edit]

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I create edit page to edit the form. When I debug it. It's showing error which is **Missing required parameters**. I already try many ways but i can't solve it. Anyone can help on this?

```
<td class="text-right">
      <a href='{{ route("email.edit",["id"=>$mailTemplate->id]) }}' class="btn btn-danger badge-pill editbtn" style="width:80px" >EDIT </a>

</td>
```

route file

```
    Route::get('api/email/create', ['as' => 'email.create', 'uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@create']);
    Route::get('automail/mail', 'Havence\AutoMailController@mail');
    Route::get('automail/index',['as'=>'email.index','uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@index']);
    Route::get('automail/edit/{id}',['as'=>'email.edit','uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@edit']);
    Route::get('automail/delete',['as'=>'email.delete','uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@destroy']);
```

Controller

```
 public function edit(AutoEmailTemplate $mailTemplates , $id)
    {
        $mailTemplates=AutoEmailTemplate::find($id);
            return view('havence.marketing.edit')->with('mailTemplates', $mailTemplates);
    }
```

Comment: pls hare your route file

Comment: @Sehdev done sharing

Comment: do a var_dump for $mailTemplate->id

Comment: it seems `$mailTemplate->id` is blank. check the output of this

Comment: how to do var_dump? @AmalSR

Comment: before <a> add `@php var_dump($mailTemplate->id); @endphp`

Comment: Then the details will be shown in view page

Comment: what u mean by output @Sehdev

Comment: it still showing same error when use ur method. @AmalSR

Comment: what is the value of {{$mailTemplate->id)}}

Comment: the id of mailTemplate. Like when you create mail template. Thn the idea will created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
<td class="text-right">
      <a href='{{ route("email.edit", $mailTemplate) }}' class="btn btn-danger badge-pill editbtn" style="width:80px" >EDIT </a>
</td>
```

The route:

```
Route::get('automail/edit/{id}',['as'=>'email.edit','uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@edit']);
```

Then in the controller you can get it:

```
 public function edit(AutoEmailTemplate $mailTemplates , $id)
{
    $mailTemplates=AutoEmailTemplate::find($id);
        return view('havence.marketing.edit', compact('mailTemplates'));
}
```

Comment: but why i need create public function example($mailTemplate) in controller

Comment: Its a example.... just use a function u already have or create a new function.

Comment: Yes... i used the same way...but why i still facing the same issue @Collin

Comment: Does the view have the variable $mailTemplate?

Comment: yes the view have the variable $mailTemplate @Collin

Comment: Can you maybe show the controller where you're returning the view